# Regular expressions to check for + sign

Tags: regex

I have written these regular expressions to check if there is a + sign between the numbers. That is, every number entered must have a + sign. (It does not matter where this sign is in the numbers, it can be the last, middle or first)
But the problem is that if I do not add the + sign to the numbers, I still will not get an error

```
^[0-9]*$|^[0-9]*[+]{1}$|^[+]{1}[0-9]*$|^[0-9]*[+]{1}[0-9]*$
```

Comment: You begin the regular expression with `^[0-9]*$` which means "all digits". That's where your plus-less strings are being accepted.

Comment: That is because of the first alternative, you can omit that one as it allows only digits. `^[0-9]*[+]$|^[+][0-9]*$|^[0-9]*[+][0-9]*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first alternative allows only optional digits without any plus sign.

You can write the pattern as

```
^[0-9]*[+]$|^[+][0-9]*$|^[0-9]*[+][0-9]*$
```

Or shorten it to

```php
^\d*\+\d*$
```

Note that both pattern allow only a `+` without any digits.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0rYOy1/1).